# Can't find any usable display type

Tags: mit-scheme

I have just installed [mit-scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) in Centos running in VirtualBox. But whenever I was trying to start Edwin editor by calling the procedure (edit) or (edwin), an error message like "Can't find any usable display type" returned. Can any one walk me through this?

Comment: What does (enumerate-graphics-types) return for you?

Comment: I kind of solve the problem by running scheme in emacs,  anyway edwin is an emacs like editor.